# Getting statistics for app functions usage

Tags: ios, splunk

I've integrated Splunk in my iOS project to monitor my App crashes.

I'm asking if there is a way to have statistics each time we go through a functionality.

For example, I want to have how many times a method has been called.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Select your log file uploaded --> Search for a particular even from the search bar --> you will see all the listed event logs --> Now click on the Arrow next to any one of these logs --> Select event actions --> Extract fields.
Now in the Example values for a Field section put few of your function names and click generate. Splunk will understand your requirements and list all the logs associated with function calls.

Copy the generated regex and put it directly on the search bar to get complete event logs of all the function calls.